# Bivariate analyses vs. Boruta/random forest for removing irrelevant variables prior to penalized regression

Tags: feature-selection, regularization, elastic-net, boruta

I will be using a penalized logistic regression (elastic net) to select variables and their relative importance for predicting an outcome. The goal is to eventually create a risk prediction model, not to understand the "true" association of individual variables with an outcome.

Update: Thanks to a poster below, I have provided some additional data. My sample size is around 800 and the outcome is fairly well balanced. I will have around 35 candidate variables to start. The reason I want to remove some potentially irrelevant variables prior to regularization is first parsimony and to avoid unintentionally adding in an item that might have an undesirable effect on the coefficient of an otherwise good predictor (e.g. avoiding adding something that could be a collider, which are fairly common in social science research). The second reason I am not sure is as justified -  if I left in variables, the coefficients in an elastic net still remain conditional on the variables in the model. While that might produce more accurate coefficients of their "true" effects, my long term goal is to  create a risk prediction model were only the selected variables (and their coefficients) be assessed in testing and in future studies and therefore don't want the coefficients too altered by too many irrelevant variables in my sample as they would not be in future model or tests of those models that did not include those variables.

To select what variables to include in an elastic net, I often see people first eliminate irrelevant variables that in the training set do not have significant bivariate associations with the outcome (e.g., running several t-tests, chi-square). I was considering instead using Boruta in the training set to remove irrelevant variables. I am aware of one reason for not choosing Boruta - that as a random forest wrapper, it is more likely to retain continuous variables and knock out binary/ordinal ones.

Are there other reasons I might want to choose to use either a series of bivariate tests or choose Boruta?

Comment: Sample size? How many candidate variables do you have? What is the reason for not starting directly with regularization? ... Please provide new information as an edit to the Q, not only in comments!

Comment: Thank you Kjetil. I have added the suggested information.